# How to replace intermediate indirect cell references

Tags: excel

In attempting to denormalize X,y,Z, coordinate data that I described in a previous post, I ended up creating multiple sheets that reference each other.

The result is that I have many cells that just reference cells on other sheets. For example, Cell Sheet1!A1 is "=Sheet2!E200" and
Sheet2!E200 is "=SomeFunction(Sheet3!K25)"

Is there any way to replace all such redirections to another cell without modification with a direct reference to the terminal cell?

In my previous example, Sheet1!A1 becomes "=SomeFunction(Sheet3!K25)"

Comment: Use "Find and Replace" with the option "Within: Workbook" ?

Comment: If `Sheet2!E200` contained a constant value would that value replace the formula in `Sheet1!A1`

Comment: Nice post on determining precedent cells:  https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/vba-determine-all-precedent-cells-a-nice-example-of-recursion/

Comment: It the sheet contained a constant, it would not be replaced. THx for the link, I am looking at the code.

Comment: Looking at your original question, I'd suggest that it will me much better to crack that particular nut than this potentially tougher one. I asked a couple more clarifying questions at that other thread, and depending on answers might be able to help you get directly from what you have to what you need. But navigating precedent cells like at Colin's great article is pretty messy, and very slow.